# How to display a list of users in Opencart 3

Tags: php, opencart-3

I don't have enough knowledge. I found an example for **admin\model\sale\order.php**
But I don't understand what should be specified in the file **admin\controller\sale\order.php**
Please tell me which is correct.

```
    public function getUsers() {
    $sql = "SELECT user_id, firstname, lastname FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "user WHERE status=1";
    $re = $this->db->query($sql);
    $user_data = array();
    foreach ($re->rows as $row) {
        $user_data [$row['user_id']] = $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname']; 
    }
    return $user_data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in `admin\controller\sale\order.php` you should load model file and retrieve data:

```
    $this->load->model('sale/order');
    $user_info = $this->model_sale_order->getUsers();
    
//////////
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($user_info); echo '</pre>';
```